# Postgres SQL to check if phone number is in the valid format

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a data in Telephone column, something as below:

```
with t (id,telephone) as (values
(1234560,'(345) 908-1234 '),
(1234561,'(345) 908-1234;ext=1234'),
(1234562 ,'(345) 908-1234;ext=12345'),
(1234563 ,'(345) 908-12345;ext=12345'),
(1234564 ,'1234567;ext=12345'),
(1234565 ,'123ABC;ext=12345'),
(1234566 ,'Ext=12345'),
(1234567 ,'+1123456789')
)
select * from t
```

Any string in the format `(XXX) XXX-XXXX;ext=XXXX(not definite)` or `(XXX) XXX-XXXX` will be considered as valid number and remaining cases will be considered as invalid

Below is what I have tried

```
select ID,
TELEPHONE,
/* To check format of the telephone */
case when TELEPHONE  similar to '\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}' then 0
when TELEPHONE  similar to '\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4};ext=%' then 0
else 1
end as TEL_IND
from t
```

In the above mentioned samples #1,#2,#3 are valid formats and remaining are invalid formats
Appreciate any help!

Comment: could you add what you've tried so far, and answers can continue from there

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the issue you're having, include the relevant portions of your code, and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to help. All you've done so far is give us a list of your requirements.

Comment: Agree.. I have written bunch of stuff trying various PnC's. I am trying to clean up and post only what is necessary. Will update the Q in some time with whatever I have done till date.

Comment: Updated the Question along with code sample

Comment: Try regex_matches()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t (id,telephone) as (values
(1234560,'(345) 908-1234 '),
(1234561,'(345) 908-1234;ext=1234'),
(1234562 ,'(345) 908-1234;ext=12345'),
(1234562 ,'(345) 908-1234;ex=12345'),
(1234563 ,'(345) 908-12345;ext=12345'),
(1234564 ,'1234567;ext=12345'),
(1234565 ,'123ABC;ext=12345'),
(1234566 ,'Ext=12345'),
(1234567 ,'+1123456789')
),
  captures AS
(
  SELECT
    t.*,
    REGEXP_MATCHES(trim(telephone), '\(([0-9]{3})\) ([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{4})(?:;ext=([0-9]*))?|.*') AS parts
  FROM
    t
)
SELECT
  *,
  Parts[1],
  Parts[2],
  Parts[3],
  Parts[4]
FROM
  captures
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/6LxJphW_)

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I am trying to split values into diff columns based on the formats as below. Is this something which you can check  [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/z2WPdaZg)

Comment: @datatester You need to be very clear on the parsing rules. For example, why do rows 63, 64 have their extension column populated, but not rows 65, 66? Same question as to my some alternates are populated but not others? Also, you should open another question, not extend an existing one.

Comment: got it. thanks. I will post a new question. Will close the existing one

Comment: @datatester Don't delete this question. Just ask an additional question.

Comment: @datatester 3am here, going to bed, here's my first approximation to what I think you want... https://dbfiddle.uk/HrgKbJEn